# How can I require two different sets of categories?

Tags: categories

I have Multi site manager running a few sites, and I use categories to set which site to show each entry on as well as topics.

ie categories: site (1), site (2), all (3), games (4), movies (5)

On the site templates, I use

To call all games for site 1 I use
category="1&4"

all games for site 2 I use
category="2&4"

But how can I show "all games in category site 1 OR category all"

this doesn't work, but makes the point:

{exp:channel:entries category="1&4 OR 3&4"}

Any ideas?

Thx!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't do this using the default `exp:channel:entries`. You gonna have to use `JOIN`s in [the query module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/query/index.html). Or [Dandy Cat](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dandy-cat).